# How did the Universe climb out of its own Big Bang black hole?

Tags: black-hole, cosmology, big-bang-theory

The Big Bang started as a singularity. That means small. All the matter in the universe was in a volume smaller than its own Schwarzchild radius. The universe was inside a black hole.

At present, the universe is big: bigger than its Schwarzchild radius. It got out of its own black hole which, they tell me, can’t be done.

How did this happen?

Comment: What have you found out in the intervening 46 years?

Comment: That I'm a bear of very little brain.

Comment: [Is the Big Bang a black hole?](https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Relativity/BlackHoles/universe.html) Also see https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3294/123208 & https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/136860/123208

Comment: Why do you think there was a black hole? And if there was, what makes you think we are now outside it? Both these assumptions should be seriously challenged. Also, space itself got bigger, which is very different to something getting bigger and escaping a black hole.

Comment: The Schwarzchild radius for the mass of the universe is roughly galactic in size. Initially, the radius of the universe was smaller than that.

Comment: "All the matter in the universe was in a volume smaller than its own Schwarzchild [sic] radius." You're confusing the whole Universe with the **observable universe**: there's simply no way to guess the volume or mass of what's beyond observation, so you can't calculate a density or Schwarzschild radius. For the *observable* universe you're ignoring metric expansion: when the universe was "smaller", so was the "ruler" measuring its Schwarzschild radius.